# What is an alias really doing?

Tags: shell, alias

I'm looking for a way to check what an alias is really doing, without having to check the `${HOME}/.profile` file, or whatever other file where you can define an alias.

For example, if I run `ll` and I have it defined in the `.profile` file as `ls -l`, then that is what is being executed.  How can I know that without having to `grep` or look into the `.profile` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias ll
```

or this:

```
type ll
```